# How to parse json data that provides another url with more data

Tags: ios, json, parsing, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm a little confused how would I parse a json API that gives me 20 objects but then gives me a key of "next" having a url that gives me another 20 objects. I'm using this [Pokemon API](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/). It gives me 4 keys: ***count, previous, results*** and ***next***. I'm trying to display them all in a collection view but not all at the same time. I would like to load more when the collection view is scrolling down.

I'm just trying to get the name at the moment. This is how my code looks like.

[image: ViewController]

[image: Json func]

[image: Pokemon Class]

I get it to load the first 20 Pokemon in the collection view. However I don't know how to load the next 20 Pokemon or the 20 after. This is how the json file looks like if the link didn't work.

[image: Pokemon api structure]

I would appreciate any help given. :)

Comment: Please do not post screenshot of code, copy/paste code instead. In the delegate method willDisplayCell, if it's at a certain limit, fetch the next batch with the url.

Comment: Sorry Nayem, new to stack over flow don't really know what people prefer screenshots or the code. I'm also new to iso development, would you mind showing me an example in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a recursive function reusing the `loadPokemonsData` function something like this:

```
func loadPokemonsData(url: String, quantity: Int?) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }


        do {
            let jsonResults = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

            let pokemonArray = jsonResults.value(forKey: "results") as! [[String: Any]]

            var isPokemonsEqualsToQuantity: Bool = false

            for pokemonData in pokemonArray {

                if let quantity = quantity {
                    guard self.pokemons.count < quantity else {
                        isPokemonsEqualsToQuantity = true
                        break
                    }
                }

                guard let name = pokemonData["name"] as? String else {
                    return
                }

                self.pokemon = Pokemon(name: name)
                self.pokemons.append(self.pokemon)
            }



            guard let nextURL = jsonResults.value(forKey: "next") as? String, !isPokemonsEqualsToQuantity else {
                for pokemon in self.pokemons {
                    print(pokemon.name)

                }
                print(self.pokemons.count)
                return
            }

            self.loadPokemonsData(url: nextURL, quantity: quantity)




        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Attach a screen of algorithm function running... it prints 791 pokemons.

[image]

Hope it helps you!

**EDITED**

Next time you ask put your code please... it will be easier help you!.

- I've updated the code to set the quantity you want (nil if you want to get all pokemons), Therefore it will only get the pokemons in the order API returns it, if you want a specific pokemons from ALL pokemons you may do a sort after obtaining all pokemons.

Comment: Thank you, Santiago it works. However the app crashes after a few runs, the api gives me an error. "Request was throttled. Expected available in 2714.0 seconds."  I now it's because of to much request to the api is there any way to fix this problem. Thanks again, for answering my main question. Ah, thanks for the advices on using code instead of screenshots. :)

Comment: Did you mean the error appears the first time you load all pokemons or after load many times all pokemons ?

Comment: Okay the code was perfect. I was putting the guard let nextURL in the for array loop, instead of outside. Was wondering why it didn't print nothing in the console, like your screenshot. However it was still loading the pokemon why?

Comment: I guess you are making something wrong, because it is not logical loading pokemons works but print it not. Make sure you are calling the print function after all pokemons are saved in the array and there are not more pokemons to load.

Comment: Hello again, @santiago. I was wondering if you can help me out once again. I was wondering if there is a way to only parse a certain amount of objects. I only want it to parse the first 721 and not the rest of the Pokemon. Didn't want to post another similar question. I've tried using a repeat and while loop but can't seem to get it to work

Comment: @LuisRamirez please see the update answer, I've changed the code.

Comment: Thank you so much @santiago, you've been a big help. Just wanted you to know. I also figure another way to parse it thanks to you but I like your way a bit better. Instead I used a if else statement. If pokemons.count <  721: self.pokemons.append(pokemon) else: break. Thanks again. Any way of adding people?